# Authorize() functionality is not working on /Account/Register when published

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, controller

I do want to have a `[Authorize()]` function on my `AccountController`s `Register` function. I simply do not want anyone to Register new accounts on my site.

```
        //[AllowAnonymous]
        [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

This works perfectly when testing on `localhost` but fails on my Azure-hosted site.
The code is perfectly the same on `localhost` as Published.

What can be the fault here? Im guessing that the code isn't beeing run propperly.

Result on `Localhost`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvsSQ.png (Correct)

Result on `Azure`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf5Ry.png (Faulty (No Autorization))

EDIT: 
Maybe this line in the web.config file is mucking it up?

```
 <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
        </modules>
      </system.webServer>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `but fails on my Azure-hosted site`?

Comment: I mean that there is no Authorization. I can enter the Registration page and create additional accounts -without the `[Authorize()]` checking my level of clearence.

Comment: Can you show the web.config settings which you have deployed to Azure?